# Usage of pfx file in gunicorn

Tags: python, ssl, gunicorn

I have a small doubt. Is there any way to use a pfx or p12 container with gunicorn?

I'm developing a python app that contains 2 api endpoints which are served using gunicorn and falcon. I want to support ssl but using pfx to set the keys and CA. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn needs a cert file and a key file. You can extract these from the pfx file. Make sure your key file is unencrypted else , you might have to enter the password while deployment